# Google Script Assistance with multiple scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, drop-down-menu

I have a script with 3 formulas. The first two are for dynamic dependent dropdowns and they work fine. However, when I add a third script for a normal dependent dropdown, the dropdown works, but it breaks the first two scripts.

```
function depDrop_(range, sourceRange) {
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true).build();
    range.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function onEdit() {
    var aCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
    var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
    if (aColumn == 13 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()) {
        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
        var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
        depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
    } else if (aColumn == 14 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()) {
        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
        var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
        depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
    }
    //second script
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true).build();
    range.setDataValidation(rule);
}

var aCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
if (aColumn == 16 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()) {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
    var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
    depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
} else if (aColumn == 17 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()) {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
    var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
    depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
}

//third script
function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
}

function onEdit() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var datass = Spreadsheet
}
```

I have tried the first 2 scripts for dynamic dropdowns and they are fine. The third script also works fine on its' own. It's when I add the 3rd script to the first 2 that breaks it.

Comment: Every function in a project has to have a different name.  It looks like your have two onEdits.  But it's hard to tell because of the poor formatting.

Comment: Code formatting.